# Fevered goof up and now wants it back

Tags: windows

My sister, who at the moment is still sick and feverish, decided last night that the view on her desktop wasn't to her liking, so she did something to it (I am guessing that was the thought that was in her brain!) and now wants it back to the way it was....as of now, the "app" icons on her desktop are all over her screen (lock screen) and all the apps used to be where you click "settings"...how in the world do I get it back to the way it was, short of going out to buy a brand new desktop?!?!?!?! I've tried researching and with me and my "I can't figure this out" brain, it seems like I'm reading the Greek language....any easy simple things I can do?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Sounds like you turned on tablet mode. Click the notification icon at the bottom right and then turn off tablet mode which is one of the buttons on the notification bar.

Comment: If the problem is just icon location, can't she move those to where she wants them?

Comment: A screen shot would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to do a rollback to a system restore point
dating from before that fatal night.
If your sister did not also disable this mechanism, it should be enabled by default.

For more information see the article
[How to Use System Restore in Windows 7, 8, and 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/),
section "How to Restore Your System to an Earlier Restore Point".